# When accessing a pointer to an array why is &myArrayPtr[0] faster than myArrayPtr.get()?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

I have a unique pointer to an array of "type", and it seems that accessing the pointer to the first element of that array through:

```
&myArrayPtr[0];
```

is faster than:

```
myArrayPtr.get();
```

considering these operations are both defined the std::unique_ptr ([] operator and get(), and the results are the same, how are these being implemented differently "behind the scenes"? It seems to be a difference of about 10 nanoseconds.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> myArrayPtr;
uint64_t number_of_elements = 1000;
myArrayPtr.reset(new int[number_of_elements]);

&myArrayPtr[0];

myArrayPtr.get();
```

Comment: Why not check the assembly and find out? It's also a good idea to provide complete details on your micro-benchmark. There's no method call when you access it directly, of course.

Comment: Obviously not a problem in the example above, but... `&myArrayPtr[0];` = Kaboom if `myArrayPtr` is null. `get()`, not so much.

Comment: Try your code at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/). It seems both ways generate the same assembly when optimization is turned on (gcc and clang, with -O2). How did you compile/measure?

Comment: oops... I goofed, they're the same, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. Just four things that I think are related to your question:

1. The implementation for your standard library's `std::unique_ptr` is there in the `<memory>` header in plain sight and you can check it out to see exactly what is different between the two. Or at least post them here; this is required information.
2. The assembly code that your compiler produces would be the ultimate place to look for these small fluctuations in speed. It's not hard getting the compiler to generate assembler as well as (or instead of) object file and perusing that. Or at least post them here; this is required information.
3. A speed difference in the scale of nanoseconds could very well depend highly on your exact CPU architecture and model, not to mention compiler details and command line switches. You should include these with your question.
4. A speed difference in the scale of nanoseconds is very highly dependent on your benchmark methodology. Do you use a timer with enough precision and accuracy? Do you repeat the experiments enough times to have confidence in your results and your margins of error? Do you know your margins of error? Do you properly warm up your CPU pipeline and caches? Do you account for OS interference and context switches? And several other things that I can think of off the top of my head (and I'm not an expert in this by any measure.) You should describe your methodology or post your complete source code that has led you to believe as you believe.

Anyways, to give you a semblance of an answer (which I admit is not adequate,) the two methods for getting the address out of a `unique_ptr` you mention are most probably not at all different. They will probably generate the exact same code (which is basically nothing more than just an `LEA` or something on x86) if you aren't generating debug code and doing proper inlining.